# "went on to" x "went onto". Do they have different meanings?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I found both of these expressions in a YouTube comment and I'm trying to find out if using "on to" or "onto" after the verb "went" makes the expression to have different meanings. Here's the comment I'm talking about:

"I don't know what the timeline was when Eric Clapton told George he was in love with Patty? Because apparently George didn't care so much because George was already having affairs. The stories of Eric-George-Patty and George-Ringo-Maureen sound similar. George told Ringo he was in love with Maureen (Ringo was having affairs too). And Eric told George he was in love with Patty. All remained good friends. Patty apparently left because of George's affairs. George I believe went to their wedding. Eric **went on to** have two kids with other women during his marriage to Patty. Life of a rock star. I think the only one who **went onto** have a normal healthy marriage was Paul and Linda. Until she passed."

Comment: to go on to do something. Not: onto, which is on a surface.

Comment: It should have been "***went on** to have ...*" in both sentences. Don't expect Youtube comments to be exemplary...

Comment: Thanks to both Lambie and Andrew for helping me with this question. Yes, I know about YouTube comments not being exemplary, but sometimes they can be. That's when it becomes important to be able to count on some help to distinguish between one and the other. Thank you again.